# Not able to move to the next loop of vm list

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a code that starts VM's in batches. I am able to start vm's in batches. I am facing an issue here where `('*adds*','*DB*','*')` are vm's containing the following wildcard names and need to be started in the following order.The script only starts the first list of vms with '*adds*' and continues to restart it in loop it does not move to the next. Any help guys.

```
$bubbleName="VmList"
           do{
                $vname=@('*adds*','*DB*','*')
                $i=0
                Write-Host "Starting VM with "$vname[$i]
                $vmList = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $bubbleName -Name $vname[$i]
        
            $batch = @{
            Skip  = 0
            First = 2
            }
          do{          
            do{

           foreach($vm in ($vmList | Select-Object @batch)){
   
                $params = @($vm.Name, $vm.ResourceGroupName)
                $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
                param($ComputerName,$serviceName)
                Start-AzVM -Name $ComputerName -ResourceGroupName $serviceName 
                } -ArgumentList $params 
               }
                Wait-Job -Job $job
                Get-Job | Receive-Job
                
                Write-Host $batch
                $batch.Skip += 2
    }
    until($batch.skip -ge $vmList.count)
    
    }while($job.state -ne "Completed")
    $i++      
        
    }while($vname[$i] -ne $null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You changed this a bit from an earlier (now deleted) version. However, I continued working on the old one and I'll share my thoughts.

If I understand correctly you want to start VMs in orders

1. *adds*
2. *db*
3. * (everything else)

Honestly, I think you're going about your loops are a little convoluted. If it were me, I'd sort the a list of all VMs according to the above order. Then code a single traditional for loop to start 2 at a time and use `Wait-Job` in the loop.

I don't have an Azure environment to test with but here are my notes from earlier:

Step 1: get the list in the order you need it. This will prevent the funky stuff you're doing with `-First` & `-Skip`:

```
# Example data, substituting for VM objects
$Objects =
@(
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "adds1"     }
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "DB1"       }
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "adds2"     }
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "DB2"       }
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "something" }
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "another"   }
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = "last"      }
)

$Objects = 
$Objects.Where( { $_.Name -match 'adds'} ) +
$Objects.Where( { $_.Name -match 'db'} )   +
$Objects.Where( { $_.Name -notmatch '(adds|db)'} )
```

Obviously this is a simulation that you'd have to adjust to your VMs. Maybe Objects will actually be defined by `Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $bubbleName -Name *`. At any rate, you should be able to get the VMs in the desired order.

Step 2: a loop to start 2 at a time, waiting for them to start before moving on to the next 2:

```
$Step = 1 
# Note: 1 means 2 at a time, $i and $i+$Step, in this case 1.
#       So the first iteration will work on index 0 & 1

# You can modify $Step to different size chunks.

For($i = 0; $i -lt $Objects.Count; ++$i )
{    
    $ii = $i + $Step

    $Jobs = 
    $Objects[$i..$ii] |
    ForEach-Object{
        # Run the Start-Job commands against the appropriate machines    
    }

    # Note: The assignment of $Jobs solves another problem. You were  only waiting
    #       for the 2nd of the 2 jobs that were started.  Now Wait-Job -Job $Job
    #       will be an array of jobs, which is allowed by the cmdlet without piping..
        
    # Wait-Job -Job $Jobs
    # ...

    # I also didn't understand why one of the loops was conditioned on While 
    # $job.State -ne 'Completed'. Wait job should be enough and the above code 
    # assumed that.

    # Reassign $i so when the loop increments naturally it's 1 past $ii.
    # Effectively this chunks 2 elements per iteration.
    $i = $ii    
}
```

Again, I don't have the right environment to test all this. But conceptually this should be enough to get you through.  I'm sorry about the variable renaming, but given the disadvantage, I had to hack my way through purely on concept.